# Why can't I install a specific version of npm and how can I do it?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm, installation

My Linux distribution is:

```
uname -a

Linux 16.04.2-Ubuntu
```

Also, my `npm` version was:

```
npm -v

3.5.2
```

I wanted to install version **3.10.10** of **npm** via this command:

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install npm@3.10.10
```

But I get these errors:

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/arvin/package.json'
npm WARN myname No description
npm WARN myname No repository field.
npm WARN myname No README data
npm WARN myname No license field.
```

And when using the same command for installed version **6.12.2** of Node.js:

```
sudo npm install nodejs@6.12.2
```

And I get these errors:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-26-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "nodejs@6.12.2"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! No compatible version found: nodejs@6.12.2
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! 0.0.0
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/arvin/npm-debug.log
```

Finally, I decided to completely remove `npm' and Node.js via these commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs
sudo apt autoremove
sudo rm -R ~/.npm
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/npm, /usr/local/share/man/man1/node, /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d, ~/.node-gyp, /opt/local/bin/node, opt/local/include/node, /opt/local/lib/node_modules
sudo npm uninstall npm
```

So, how can I install npm v3.10.10 and Node.js v6.12.2 in [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus)?

Comment: Have you tried installing node first and then npm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `npm` to install `npm`, you need to use the `-g` flag to signal that the package should be installed globally. If you install without the -g flag, it will try to find a `package.json` file in the local directory.

```
sudo npm install -g npm@3.10.10
```

Btw, you cannot install Node.js with npm. To manage Node.js versions, you can use either `nvm` or `n`. I recommend using *[n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n)*.

Comment: @Unkas This is with the assumption that npm is already installed and just want to change the version. To install npm for the first time, you need to install NodeJs first.